# invoke parent process's process.stdout.clearLine() in children process

Tags: node.js

I am output some log to terminal from `children process` which generate by `spawn()`.
And now I need `clearLine() and cursorTo(0)` which just can invoke in parent process since the `stdout` should be `isTTY`. What should I do to invoke clearLine and cursorTo(0) in children process?